# MongoDB Geospatial Haystack Indexing

Tags: c#, mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-.net-driver

How do you create a [Geospatial Haystack Index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Haystack+Indexing) using the 10gen C# Driver for MongoDB

JS Example:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({ pos : "geoHaystack", type : 1 }, { bucketSize : 1 })
```

C# Example that does not work:

```
BsonDocument keys = new BsonDocument();
keys.Add("pos", "geoHaystack");
keys.Add("type", "1");

IMongoIndexKeys indexKeys = new IndexKeysDocument(keys);

IndexOptionsDocument indexOptions = new IndexOptionsDocument("bucketSize", new BsonInt32(1));

collection.CreateIndex(indexKeys, indexOptions);
```

Gives this error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoSafeModeException : Safemode detected an error 'can only have 1 index plugin / bad index key pattern'. (Response was { "err" : "can only have 1 index plugin / bad index key pattern", "code" : 13007, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 6, "ok" : 1.0 }).

So if I remove the 'type' key, like this:

```
BsonDocument keys = new BsonDocument();
keys.Add("pos", "geoHaystack");

IMongoIndexKeys indexKeys = new IndexKeysDocument(keys);

IndexOptionsDocument indexOptions = new IndexOptionsDocument("bucketSize", new BsonInt32(1));

collection.CreateIndex(indexKeys, indexOptions);
```

I get this error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoSafeModeException : Safemode detected an error 'no other fields specified'. (Response was { "err" : "no other fields specified", "code" : 13317, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 7, "ok" : 1.0 }).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was index direction was specified as a  string value

```
 keys.Add("type", "1");
```

Change it to integer

```
 keys.Add("type", 1);
```

This will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with:

```
IMongoIndexKeys keys = new IndexKeysDocument {
    { "Position", "geoHaystack" },
    { "type", 1 }
};

IMongoIndexOptions options = new IndexOptionsDocument {
    { "bucketSize", 1 }
};

collection.EnsureIndex(keys, options);
```

The problem I had was to do with data already loaded in the collection.

You should then be able to query with:

```
var command = new CommandDocument {
    { "geoSearch", "foo" },
    { "near", new BsonArray { 33, 33 } },
    { "maxDistance", 6 },
    { "search", new BsonDocument { { "type", "restaurant" } } },
    { "limit", 30 }
};
database.RunCommand(command);
```